# send email to all subscriber (all user) PHP & MYSQL (25,000 mail per day)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where I have put a subscriber page. And subscribers details like email and name is stored in mysql DB.

Lets say, I have 1000 subscribed users in mysql database. If I want to send an email to all users, what should i do? mail shouldn't go in SPAM

please tell me any tutorial or website TO DO

Comment: What do you tried so far? Just select all e-mail-addresses and loop them sending mails...

Answer (score 0):

First please consult your favourite search engine.

Anyway here's a tutorial:
http://woork.blogspot.de/2008/01/simple-newsletter-system-using-php.html?m=1

You should consider to take a look at php's MySQL and mail functionalities though.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a newsletter script I made & updating it: http://speedosoftwares.tk/showthread.php?tid=12&pid=16#pid16

here is a code to loop through the email

```
                    $mailToList = array();
                    $getEmails = $consite->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `mail_list`");
                    if($getEmails->rowCount() != 0) {
                        while($row_info = $getEmails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $emails = $row_info['email'];
                            array_push($mailToList,$emails);
                        }
                        foreach($mailToList as $wmEmail){
                            mail($wmEmail,$subject,$content."\r\n\r\nUnsubscribe by going to: url.tld",$headerss);
                            echo('Mail sent to: '.$wmEmail.'<br />');
                        }
                        $message = 'Successfully sent the Email(s)!';
                    }else{
                        $message = 'Email failed to be sent, None emails are found!';
                    }
```

edit:
this is used in my script
it will echo each email account it's sent to
also a must know

ALWAYS ADD AN UNSUBSCRIBE LINK else you're going to ignore a legal fact for "spam mail"

Comment: this does not contain an email sent status if a specific emails are individually sent or not.